# The slider's values are transferred in the socket, but the slider visual position doesn't change

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, slider, uislider

I have a connection between iPod client and C server. 
I can send the data of the slider as I move the slider, and get the data on the server correctly. Only problem is the blue point of the slider doesn't move, nor does the label under it change the slider's value. When I disconnect, the blue point moves to the point it should be and the label shows its value. Here are the codes:

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
  switch (streamEvent)
  {         
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        event = @"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable";
        connectButton.enabled = NO;
        disconnectButton.enabled = YES;

        if (theStream == oStream)
        {
         //send data
             const uint8_t *buffer = (const uint8_t *)[dataSlider UTF8String];  
             NSInteger err = [self writeToServer:buffer];                 
             if ( err == -1)
                NSLog(@"Error sending data."); 
             else   
                NSLog(@"Success sending data.");
        }
        break;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender 
{ 
   UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender; 
   progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f); 
   sliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt]; 
   sliderLabel.text = sliderValue; 
   dataSlider = sliderValue;
}
```

This is the way it should work: the server is always asking for something to printf. I move the slider and send its value, whenever the server calls read().

Problem: the slider doesn't visually move, but its value changes (i can see it in the server's printfs).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without any code its almost impossible to have any thoughts. Have you tried setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: hum... basically what i have regarding the slider is:
`- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender 
{ 
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender; 
    progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f); 
    sliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt]; 
    sliderLabel.text = sliderValue; 
    dataSlider = sliderValue;
}`

And i use the dataSlider when calling the `[self writeToServer:buffer];`

No, i don't know, im gonna look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the constant "knowing that the stream *had space available*" was clogging the program and UI. I changed the flow of the program to wait for a message from the sever and only after that it would send the data. Here it is:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable";
        if (theStream == iStream)
         {           
            //read data
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;
            while ([iStream hasBytesAvailable])
            {
                len = [iStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0)
                {
                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    if (nil != output)
                    {                 
                        //Now that the server gave its signal to move on, send data to server

                        NSString *data = [[torqueValue stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:angleValue];
                        const uint8_t *buffer2 = (const uint8_t *)[data UTF8String];  
                        NSInteger err = [self writeToServer:buffer2];

                        if ( err == -1)
                            NSLog(@"Erro a enviar os dados."); 
                        else   
                            NSLog(@"Transmitiu com sucesso.");

                    }
                }
            }    
         }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be two problems:

1. You need to call `setNeedsDisplay`.
2. You are using a synchronous/blocking connection with the server. If you use a synchronous/blocking communication then everything, including UI update, will wait until the communication is over. If that is the case then use a asynchronous connection. As the UI is updated when you are disconnected, this is the most probable problem.

Comment: hum.. please correct me if i´m wrong. I make the connection, then the server goes into read() state (blocked). When the iOS fires the event *NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable*, it sends the current value of the Slider. Isn't that asynchronous? (Note that the server just reads and printf repeatedly. Maybe that might be understood as synchronous inside the iOS App, no?)

Comment: Looks like this is the problem. Please add the related codes in the question so that other members can check that. I have not used low level sockets directly in iPhone, so not fully sure what is going on.

Comment: What if i did the slider stuff in a different thread? I've never used threads..:s

Comment: The UI update should be done in main thread. You can start a new thread for communicating with server.

Comment: @taskinoor yeah.. that's what i'm gonna try next. thks for the tip

Comment: @taskinoor do you have any guide or something that could help me set up the threads correctly? i am following the Apress beginnig iphone 4 development, but without success.. I quite don't understand what and where should i set up the threads.. i think that the `-stream:handleEvent:` should be in a different thread, but i don't know how to code that.. thks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hum.. i got it working, but kinda laggy :s the code used was: (in the `stream:handleEvent:` method)

```
case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        event = @"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable";
        connectButton.enabled = NO;
        disconnectButton.enabled = YES;

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        if (theStream == oStream)
        {
            //send data
            const uint8_t *buffer = (const uint8_t *)[dadosSlider UTF8String];  
            NSInteger err = [self writeToServer:buffer];
            // [msg release];

            if ( err == -1)
                NSLog(@"Erro a enviar os dados."); 
            else   
                NSLog(@"Transmitiu com sucesso.");


        }
});
        break;
```

Ideas on how to get it working flawlessly? Thks

(Just to be clear. The aim here is for the iPod only send data at the moment the server asks for a `read()`)

Comment: well today i went a bit forward.. on the server side i wrote a `getchar()` right after every read and printf (in the end of the cycle) and what i found out is that after i move the slider from 11 (initial value) to 20 for example, after i press any key several times the result i get from the printf is still 11 and not 20. Another thing i noticed is that the NSLog keeps getting the signal for `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`and then sends the data continuously even after the `read()`call from the server and being in a halt state. Ideas? Should i study asynchronous more deep?

Comment: Just to be clear. The aim here is for the iPod only send data at the moment the server asks for a `read()`